# GTK AND GLADE : Drawing a number in Cairo C, trying to convert an integer into a char*

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, cairo

I'm trying to draw a number in Cairo, but the only way that I've seen of doing, is with this steps:

```
void dibuje(cairo_t *cr,int numero){
    cairo_text_extents_t extents;

    char *ut = "22";    

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0,0,0);

    cairo_select_font_face (cr, "Sans",CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);

    cairo_set_font_size (cr, 12.0);
    cairo_text_extents (cr, ut, &extents);


    cairo_move_to (cr,300,300 );
    cairo_show_text (cr, ut);
}
```

In that way I only draw "22",  but I want to draw the number I receive per parameter, the other solution would be to convert that number to a char *, however, I do not know how to do it

Comment: You have not used `numero` but hard-coded one example value. Perhaps try `char ut[42]; sprintf(ut, "%d", numero);` Why `[42]`? Because it is larger than the longest string you'll get from a 64-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from WeatherVane: you need to use sprintf instead of cairo_text_extends, like this:

```
  void dibuje_numero(cairo_t *cr, int numero, int posx, int posy){          
    cairo_move_to(cr, posx, posy);
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", numero);
    cairo_show_text(cr, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean WeatherVane gave you the `sprintf` solution?